# Keeping the Screen Turned off While Getting Inputs

Tags: linux, x11, xrandr, gpu, dpms

I need to run a set of (**graphical**) **benchmarks** with the screen **disabled**. The following command did **not** work:

```
xset dpms force off
```

Because any keyboard/mouse **input** would **re-enable** the screen. The **other** option was the following:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --off
```

This turns off the screen for a **second**, then, causes the following **segmentation fault**:

```
gnome-shell[25737]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f3d02ef9210 sp 00007ffeee4e1fd8 error 4 in libmutter-2.so.0.0.0[7f3d02e99000+156000]
```

How can the problem be **solved**? Is there any **other** user/kernel level alternative?

---

P.S.: This question is also asked in [Superuser](https://superuser.com/q/1805444/1037926) and the [Xorg Mailing List](https://lists.x.org/archives/xorg/2023-August/061427.html).